# What is the JavaScript equivalent of C# Server.URLEncode?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, javascript, http

What is the JavaScript equivalent of C# Server.URLEncode?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
encodeURI()
```

http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/#ref-js-msdn

Answer (score 8):

No, `encodeURIComponent()` exactly.

Comment: I really find it hard to believe that this is your first answer after 476 questions. Surely it befits something more than this lousy comment of mine :D

Comment: This question may become famous, simply because of this answer! However, isn't this answer more correct?

Answer (score 4):

There’s a wonderful article on xkr.us [comparing javascript’s various escape functions](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/). Do read it for details, but here’s a quick summery:

- `escape()` — don’t use: does not understand non-ASCII characters, and does not escape some important URI characters, such as `+`.
- `encodeURI()` — encodes an entire URI: as such, it leaves `?` and `&` unencoded.
- `encodeURIComponent()` — encodes a component in a query string (this is usually the one you want, and appears to be the equivalent of [`Server.URLEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525738(v=vs.90).aspx)).