# did javascript or jquery has method as Server.UrlEncode() in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

did javascript or jquery has method as Server.UrlEncode() in asp.net

eg:when using

```
  $.get("a.aspx?pk=1&k="+kvale, function(data) {
            dosth(data);
            });
```

url must encode

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848715/what-is-the-javascript-equivalent-of-c-server-urlencode

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to encode a URL in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert any string to a URL-encoded string (suitable for transmission as a query string or, generally speaking, as part of a URL) using the JavaScript functions `escape`, `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent`.

```
escape('https://www.stackoverflow.com/?wow.php')
"https%3A//www.stackoverflow.com/%3Fwow.php"
```

Source:
http://www.javascripter.net/faq/escape.htm